# Does the battle bus honking signify anything?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

In Fortnite, every time I place a marker on the map before dropping, the bus will honk. For some reason, every time I jump when it honks, I will have an almost perfect drop.
This happening many times over again has led me to believe that epic made something to calculate when you should drop and made the bus honking signify when you should drop. 
I don't know about any proof, so I'm asking the community here if they can show proof.

Comment: There are a large number of posts talking about the bus honking when the bus reaches the closest distance to your pin, but there is no official documentation from Epic that 'proves' it- what evidence do you need?

Comment: @NickS the only kind of evidence I really wanted was a few people just like me that have experienced the bus's honk at a certain time that benefits you. Thank you. I didn't know that there were.

Comment: [link to reddit post with people saying similar things](https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/8c8g9e/battle_bus_horn_signals_when_to_drop/)

Comment: @NickS if there are a large amount of posts confirming this, it might be handy to have an answer consolidating them. Also there might be someone out there that has done or is willing to do some experimentation. Congratz TBNR Blur, this is a pretty good first question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very complicated question that doesn't have a nice, clean answer. I will post all the information I can find about this phenomenom here, and I encourage you to do the same.

**Note**: While there is only one link that specifically mentions this happening in OP's ask, many more comments on the other threads linked mention similar experiences. This isn't as simple as just adding Support vs Opposing

**Evidence FOR the phenomenon:**

- [u/harryday123 believes as of 3 months ago that the sound signals when to drop, similar experiences reported by others](https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/8c8g9e/battle_bus_horn_signals_when_to_drop/)

**Evidence AGAINST the phenomenon:**

- [A senior user on Fortnite's forums believes the horn noise doesn't mean anything](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/forums/battle-royale/royale-with-cheese/441191-can-anyone-explain-exactly-what-information-the-battle-bus-gives-as-it-honks)

**Evidence that doesn't support or deny phenomenon:**

- [a user believes that the bus always honks halfway if you *don't* set a marker, others have varying opinions both ways](https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/7qfhgj/is_it_true_that_when_the_bus_beeps_that_is_the/)
- [The official patch notes say that as of 5.1, the marker makes some audio queue when close, doesn't mention bus](https://www.polygon.com/fortnite/2018/7/24/17606610/fortnite-patch-v5-1-change-list-birthday-compact-smg-playground)
- [a user had a suggestion 26 days ago that Epic *should add* this functionality to the game](https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/8uj4m1/make_the_battle_bus_honk_when_it_goes_past_our/)

**Conclusion:**

Overall, there isn't enough evidence to conclusively prove (or deny) that the phenomenon exists. This requires in-game testing, and I will help contribute by downloading the game at some point- unless someone else beats me to it. I am making this answer a wiki so that other users may add their insights and experiences.

Comment: After seeing this, all I can come up with is think however you like about the honking  bus. There's so much both ways that it's hard to come up to one side. I still believe that it doesn't honk randomly, though.